# using JavaScript code to submit a hidden html input using the GET method without using type=”submit”, via an event

Tags: javascript, html

in JavaScript technical interview questions I was asked to write a code that submit a hidden html input using the GET method without using type=”submit”, via an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `submit()` method:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('form').submit();
});
```

```html
<form method="get" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" value="test" hidden>
  <button type="button">Go</button>
</form>
```

---

If you don't want extra JavaScript you can use an inline event listener. It's bad practice to mix HTML and JavaScript but it works:

```html
<form method="get" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" value="test" hidden>
  <button type="button" onclick="document.querySelector('form').submit();">Go</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand your question correct but you can add a click event or similar to the triggerElement and preventDefault inside the callback. Then you can read out the values in the hidden or non hidden fields and submit via xhr.